# In Karate - Feature file calling from another feature file along with variable value

Tags: karate

My apologies it seems repetitive question but it is really troubling me.

I am trying to call one feature file from another feature file along with variable values. and it is not working at all.

Below is the structure I am using.

*****my request json having variable name***.** **Filename:InputRequest.json**

```
{
  "transaction" : "123",
  "transactionDateTime" : "#(sTransDateTime)"
}
```

**my featurefile1 : ABC.Feature**

`Background`:

```
  * def envValue = env
  * def config = { username: '#(dbUserName)', password: '#(dbPassword)', url: '#(dbJDBCUrl)', driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"};
  * def dbUtils = Java.type('Common.DbUtils')            
* def request1= read(karate.properties['user.dir'] + 'InputRequest.json')
* def endpoint= '/v1/ABC'
* def appDb = new dbUtils(config);
```

Scenario: ABC call

```
* configure cookies = null
Given url endpoint

And request request1
When method Post
Then status 200
```

**Feature file from which I am calling ABC.Feature**

```
@tag1
**my featurefile1: XYZ.Feature**

    `Background`: 
    
          * def envValue = env
    
    Scenario: XYZ call
       
    * def sTransDateTime = function() { var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat'); var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+00:00'"); return sdf.format(new java.util.Date()); }
    
    * def result = call read(karate.properties['user.dir'] + 'ABC.feature') { sTransDateTime: sTransDateTime }
```

> **Problem is,**

1. While executing it, runnerTest has tag1 configured to execute.
   Currently, it is ignoring entire ABC.feature to execute and also not generating cucumber report.
2. If I mention the same tag for ABC.feature (Which is not expected for me as this is just reusable component for me ) then it is being executed but **sTransDateTime**  value is not being passed from XYZ.feature to ABC.feature. Eventually, InputRequest.json should have that value while communicating with the server as a part of the request.

I am using 0.9.4 Karate version. Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this:

```
{ sTransDateTime: '#(sTransDateTime)' }
```

And read this explanation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#call-vs-read

I'm sorry the other part doesn't make sense and shouldn't happen, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thank you for redirecting me at this link @Peter Thomas

* def login = read('login.feature')
* call login

is the lifesaver for me.